# SQL Ask for a number and display > than number

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I'm new to SQL and I've the following question to complete:

Write the SQL code to ask for a number and display all employees that who earn
more commission than the number provided. The prompt should say “money please”.

So the first statement I have is:

```
SELECT E.ENAME, E.COMM 
  FROM EMP E
 WHERE e.comm > &MoneyPlease;
```

But this only works once because once you have given the value for MoneyPlease it is kept, and if I enter text it errors out.

So I'm trying to get it to prompt for a value each time it is ran, convert it to number, call out if a non numeric parameter is entered.

Below is what I have so far, I've tried moving components around, for example combining the selects to one line, and the forms to one line. But I keep getting errors no matter what changes I make, and I'm not familiar enough to know which ones mean I'm at lease going in the right direction. Feels more like I'm just taking stabs in the dark at this point.

Any direction would be appreciated.

```
Accept MoneyPlease prompt 'Money Please  '
Column MoneyPlease NEW_Value MoneyPlease

select nvl(numeric('&MoneyPlease'), '*Unknown*') MoneyPlease
  from Dual,

Prompt 'Is this correct?'

Prompt 'Enter to continue, CTRL + C to esc'

Pause

SELECT E.ENAME, E.COMM 
  FROM EMP E 
 WHERE e.comm > &MoneyPlease;
```

Comment: This is home work -- if you don't know at this level you should ask your professor.

Comment: I'm going through sample questions for an exam

Comment: First: Which RDBMS are you using? You have tagged both oracle and sql-server. It can't be both. Please fix your tags

Comment: Next: You should validate your input in application layer and only send it to database level when it's correct

Comment: @POD -- this is my point -- it is a sample question -- if you have no clue how to answer it then talk to your professor.  WE DON'T KNOW, we didn't take the class.  The question as written makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't have a built-in `numeric()` function, and that query isn't finished properly - it ends with a comma instead of a semicolon. In SQL*Plus with default settings (specifically `sqlblanklines` defaulted to `off`) that query is just silently ignored; is SQL Developer (or with `set sqlblanklines on`) the rest of the script is treated as part of that same query, which ends up with `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`.

Both clients understand [`accept`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve005.htm#SQPUG026), which you are already using, but also understand the `number` data type restriction:

> NUM[BER]
>
> Makes the variable a NUMBER datatype. If the reply does not match the datatype, ACCEPT gives an error message and prompts again.

If you simplify your script to:

```
accept MoneyPlease number prompt 'Money Please '

SELECT E.ENAME, E.COMM
  FROM EMP E
 WHERE e.comm > &MoneyPlease;
```

then if you run that through SQL*Plus and give a non-numeric value you just get re-prompted for a number:

```
SQL> @your_script

Money Please abc
SP2-0425: "abc" is not a valid NUMBER
Money Please 123
old   3:  WHERE e.comm > &MoneyPlease
new   3:  WHERE e.comm >        123
... -- query results
```

In SQL Developer the same thing happens, but the prompt the for value is a pop-up dialog, and the SP-0425 message goes into the script output window.